# $http scope issue with variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$http({
    url: "php/myuId.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        'userId': userId,
    },
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        $scope.myId= data;
//return last inserted id
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    });
//can't use it outside?
        $scope.user.push({
        "userId":  $scope.myId,

    });
```

strange, $scope.myId isn't change when I used it outside of scope $http, so I can't push my last inserted id to front end.

Comment: No problems with this code. Show your full view & controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using .apply();  The change in JS won't be seen, or reflected in the UI if you don't.

```
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.apply(function(){
        $scope.myId = data;
    });
})
```

Comment: what if my $scope.myId alrdy been set to certain value, will it update like a normal variable do? says $scope.myId was 123, and after declared within the apply scope, what will happen? the value got updated?

Comment: I got an error using apply, it says undefined is not a function

Comment: Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.2/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

Comment: `The change in JS won't be seen, or reflected in the UI if you don't.`  Angular does see changes in current situation. `$scope.$apply()` will throw an `digest in progress` exception

Comment: @Didar_Uranov don't get that.. take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464529/scope-apply-returned-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function?noredirect=1#comment35973175_23464529

Comment: Just like @Didar_Uranov wrote, you should definitely not use $apply like this in a $http callback.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that it is asynchronous, so you don't have the data yet until the promise returns. You could either put the $scope.user.push inside the success callback, or use $scope.$watch("myId"... to register when the value is updated.