# $scope.apply returned TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
    $http({
        url: "php/insert.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            'myId': myId
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.currentId = data;
        });

    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {});

    $scope.tabs.push({
        "currentId": $scope.currentId
    });
```

I try to use $scope.apply to update my bind-ed $scope.currentId but it returned returned TypeError: undefined is not a function for my $scope.apply, any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: I just saw this question in your other question, probably don't need to make a whole new one. Change it to $scope.$apply(function..

Comment: possible duplicate of [$http scope issue with vairable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464350/http-scope-issue-with-vairable)

Comment: @ZackArgyle Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.2/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

Comment: @Phil no answer there at all, doesn't work

Comment: That is why I said not to ask this question. It IS the correct answer to what you asked here, but not to what you asked in your other question.

Comment: @ZackArgyle so what's the problem? $apply still don't work

Comment: Update your question with full view and controller code

Comment: @user3522457: Why use `$apply()` ? `$http` is Angular-context-aware and will digest your changes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `$apply` in `$http` because `$http` it self will wrap your code with `$apply` and calling `$apply` in `$apply` will throw error.

your code should be like this

```
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.currentId = data;
})
```